# Do Germans use the english word "Dear" often?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Do Germans use the English word "Dear"often? Are they being formal or friendly/endearment in texts messages from German friends?

Comment: Germans tend to use english words if they think it's cool but although it seems like half of german language is english, this is still rare and I wonder how you got the idea they would say "dear" at all?

Comment: Maybe you heard **dir**? That's the personal pronoun *du* in dative.

Comment: No. I think Janka's version is the most likely. Be careful, their pronouncation is nearly so blurry as the English, but contrary the English, it is not very widely known and teached.

Comment: It was sent in a text "Dear" then my name not dir

Comment: Look at that, context! Could be anything from "used Dear because all the examples in his English textbook in school used it, and he/she doesn't know any alternatives" up to "loves you." If I had to guess, he/she tried to use an appropriate, but-more-personal-than-hello greeting.

Comment: Oh and it's not used at all between German speakers or in everyday language, see Björn's answer

Comment: @mary Was the rest of the message in German? In any case, this looks like the equivalent to you writing "Lieber X, how are you doing?" to the same friend. Something that only occurs between friends with different native languages, not something that would occur in a conversation between two German speakers.

Comment: @Mary: as there seems to be some confusion you may have to tell us if the texts you are referring to are written in German or in English.

Answer (score 9):

No, Germans do not use *dear* often, they do not even use it seldomly.

Comment: They rather use it *not at all* ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is what we learn in school how to start a letter.

> Dear Granny, I hope you are well...

or:

> Dear Father Christmas, bring me...

My guess would be that the people you have encountered using this haven't had a lot of exposure to an English-speaking environment and thus haven't practised anything other than their school English.